# Animation is too fast in Three.js

Tags: animation, three.js, collada, skeletal-animation

I'm loading my model and skeletal animation using the ColladaLoader into Three.js and it appears to be doing the right movements as far as I can tell, but the animation is ridiculously fast for some reason. How do you control the speed of the animation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var animation = THREE.Animation( mesh, animationData );
animation.timeScale = 1/5 ; // add this
```

the default `timeScale` is 1, reduce it to lower your animation

Comment: Thanks, but this had no effect. Maybe there's something else wrong.

Comment: can you link an example of your scene ?

Comment: I had to create my scene on plunkr so you could see it, but in doing so I created a version that actually works as expected! So the problem must be somewhere else in my code. I'll keep digging. Your solution does work to alter the speed of the animation though on the working version so I'll credit you with the answer. Thanks for your help! btw, here's the animation if you're curious: http://plnkr.co/edit/clHxI7kHL6ylZ2O6I5Uw?p=preview

Comment: @adam0101 awesome, nice job !

Comment: Figured it out. I wanted it tied to an audio track so I was passing in audio.currentTime into the animation handler. I need to figure out how to get the delta of that time.

Comment: what is animationData?